# How to model complex "or logic" on an activity diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram

Is there a way to model complex logic on an activity diagram?
For example A = B && (C || D || F) , where B, C, D, F are booleans.
I know that it is easy to do the AND operator with decision node, but what about several OR conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from specifying it in guard (as Thomas has shown), you can of course also draw it.

[image]

You can think of AND as flows being in sequence, and OR as parallel.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. Simply put the expression into a guard:

[image]